# develop eclipse builder plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, builder

I want to develop an  eclipse plugin that will check before each build if an XML file contains some parameters, and will generate warning if not.

I opened an eclise plugin project "incremental project builder" it has a sample in it named "sample builder" I've tried to run it and see how does it generate the warnings but I cannont see even how to debug it. (when I debug it it does enter any function of the builder"

do you have an idea, or any other sample how to do such builder?

Answer (score 2):

To debug a builder plugin you need to "Debug -> Debug Configure As..." and from that debug configurations dialog select "Eclipse Application", click the New Launch Configuration button and finally click on the Debug button.  This will bring up a test Eclipse workspace that's running not only your installed plugins but any plugins (like your sample builder plugin) that  you have developed in your original development workspace.

You next have to create a project in the test workspace to hold files like the XML file you want to validate.  In the .project file of that project you need to add a definition of the builder you've created.  Look at the .project file in your builder plugin sample (in the original development workspace) for an example of how the java builders are defined.

Once your builder has been defined as a builder for your project (in the test workspace) and that project contains the XML you want to validate then your builder will be invoked whenever any file in that project is modified.

You can set breakpoints in your code in the development workspace so that you can stop execution of your builder in the test workspace.